# How to test MS Fakes when NUNIT is installed?

Tags: nunit, visual-studio-2013, microsoft-fakes

I installed TestDriven.NET to test some older NUNIT tests.  Now I need to test some MS Fakes based tests.  However, the only options I have is to run and debug tests are TestDriven.NET.

I'm using VS.NET 2013.

How do I re-enable MS Fakes test runner?

Comment: You mean the Visual Studio Test Runner? You somehow disabled that entirely?

Comment: The one that runs the MS Fakes based test.  I guess that is the VS.NET test runner.  I'm not sure.  I don't know if I disabled it. How do I checked?  It doesn't seem to work if TestDriven.NET is installed, TD.NET takes over.

Comment: Which version of VS are you on? What has changed post installing testdriven.net that makes you feel that fakes has been disabled?